# Conversion of strings to integers on arm64?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsinteger, arm64

I've got a small chunk of code which I've noticed is behaving differently for `arm64` targets. I'm fetching a numeric string from JSON data, and then using `integerValue` to convert the string to an integer. The string generally has thousands separators, in the form of a comma.

On non-64bit targets, (iPhone 4/s, 5/s, etc), everything works perfectly and I get the correct integer regardless of whether there is a comma separating the thousands. However, on `arm64`, `integerValue` only returns the first "chunk" of numbers, before the separator comma. I've included the code and a sample result to show what exactly is happening:

```
NSInteger value = [BTCValue integerValue];
[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = value;
```

For example, on non-64bit targets:
`BTCValue = @"54,321.00"` and `value = 54321`.

On arm64 targets, however:
`BTCValue = @"54,321.00"` and `value = 54`.

It doesn't seem to matter whether `value` is an int or an NSInteger, the same thing happens regardless. Is there something that I'm missing? I don't understand why everything works properly on armv7 but not arm64.

Comment: The idea that the processor is the factor causing this is a little hard to swallow. Are you sure the localization on your arm64 device is the same  as the others?

Comment: I'm running the same code on the iPhone simulator. Locale on both is the same.

Comment: Can you clarify that remark? _None_ of your testing is on a device? Or you've tested on: a) non-64-bit devices, b) 64-bit devices, c) non-64-bit simulator, **and** d) 64-bit simulator? And _both_ b and d display this behavior, while a and c do not?

Comment: I've tested on both the simulator and non-64bit devices, but not on a 64bit **device**, which I don't currently have access to. I've only been able to get this behavior on the 64bit _simulator_, but I don't know if it would occur on an actual device or not.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that your ARM64 device has a locale setting that is causing the comma to be treated as a decimal or simply as non-numeric text.

In general, you're better off using `NSNumberFormatter`.

[Apple docs on `NSNumberFormatter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: I'll give it a shot with NSNumberFormatter. The strange thing is that this is occurring on the iPhone simulator; I know that all of my simulators are set to the same locale.

Comment: You _know_, or you've _checked_, @Radrider33? It's possible to have different number formatting settings on the different simulators.

Comment: And you're certain that each of your scenarios has a comma in the string?